# Expiration of a session with discord oauth2

Tags: php, session-cookies

I use Discord oauth2 on my site, I would like that when a user connects, his session lasts for example 48h without automatic disconnection.

Here's what I've set up;

include/discord.php :

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 172800);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 172800);
session_start();

function url($clientid, $redirect, $scope)
{
    $state = gen_state();
    return 'https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=' . $clientid . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect . '&expires_in=172800&scope=' . $scope . "&state=" . $state;
}
```

include/login.php :
`ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 172800); ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 172800); session_set_cookie_params(172800);`

include/.htaccess :
`php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 172800`

php.ini
`session.gc_maxlifetime = 172800`

user.ini
`session.gc_maxlifetime = 172800`

Despite all this, if I leave my site for about 1 hour, I'm automatically logged out.
I've looked hard for a solution but haven't found anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: Also bear in mind that a session expires as soon as the browser is closed, whatever the session lifetime indicated.